# Are html tags allowed as value of title attribute on image

Tags: html, jquery-plugins

I already found this existing question

[Is this possible in XHTML: tags in a title-attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362158/is-this-possible-in-xhtml-tags-in-a-title-attribute)

...but it seems to be about browser-rendered title attribute.

I'm using a jQuery plugin to render the title attribute, called Tooltip by Flowplayer.

I can already tell you that the rendering of HTML tags contained in title attributes with this plugin WORKS.  It shows nicely in FF3, IE7, IE8 and recent versions of Safari, Chrome and Opera.

My question is: is it "legit"?

I only found that the value of title attribute should be "text".  Does it mean plain text or "string"?

Considering that most browsers display the HTML correctly with the jQuery plugin applied, would you think it's fair to put those tags, EVEN if they're not "officially" authorized ??

Comment: seems legit to me.  If you look at the source that is generated from this in the browser, it turns `<span style='color:red'>blah</span>` into `&lt;span style='color:red'&gt;blah&lt;/span&gt;`

Comment: In Firefox 5 the < > characters are still there, not the entities.  But well, the jQuery plugin renders it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer would be to check out directly with a validator (http://validator.w3.org/). If the page is not on the web, open it in your browser and take the source code generated by jQuery and paste it in the validator's Direct Input tab.

If you want to know what is legit and what isn't, W3.org is the reference.

Comment: I just tested it and it passes with HTML5 at least EDIT: and 4.01 transitional

Comment: Shows 4 warnigns and 4 errors here (HTML 4.01 Transitional and XHTML 1.0 transitional)...  One of them says: *"Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values "*

Answer (score 1):

The W3C say on http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#element-definitions

> 3.2.4.1 Attributes
>
> Except where otherwise specified, attributes on HTML elements may have
>   any string value, including the empty string. Except where explicitly
>   stated, there is no restriction on what text can be specified in such
>   attributes.

This is a string value it is not markup (elements with or without attributes and text nodes). Firefox 19.0.2 and Chrome 25.0.1364.160 with no plugin, both display the raw string without trying to render it as markup. This I believe is the correct behaviour as an attribute is a text string not markup. So if you want to display html code it is fine (but it should really be html encoded) if you want to get a browser to render the html code without your JQuery plugin it is not going to happen. So your plugin is asking your browser to do something unnatural. Isn't there a better way to achieve the same effect?